# antlr-4.13.0 python3.6 lexer ATNDeserializer failure on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, antlr4, lexer

I'm building a simple compiler that uses a csv file as input. I was using antlr4 in the past for this project but recently tried to upgrade from pyhton 3.6 to 3.11, which only partially worked and have reverted back to 3.6.

After that change antlr only partially works. The grammar file seems to work well and the grun successfully reads my input files.

But, when I try building the entire project the lexer class fails with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rt2.py", line 21, in <module>
    from rt2Lexer import rt2Lexer
  File "/newvolume/mmcgrego/X/EDA/rt_a/rt2Lexer.py", line 151, in <module>
    class rt2Lexer(Lexer):
  File "/newvolume/mmcgrego/X/EDA/rt_a/rt2Lexer.py", line 153, in rt2Lexer
    atn = ATNDeserializer().deserialize(serializedATN())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/antlr4/atn/ATNDeserializer.py", line 60, in deserialize
    self.reset(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/antlr4/atn/ATNDeserializer.py", line 90, in reset
    temp = [ adjust(c) for c in data ]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/antlr4/atn/ATNDeserializer.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    temp = [ adjust(c) for c in data ]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/antlr4/atn/ATNDeserializer.py", line 88, in adjust
    v = ord(c)
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

I've tried reinstalling antlr4 and java but still having the same problem.

How can I perform an absolutely clean install of antlr4 on CentOS 7 and java 3.6? Is there an older version on antlr4 that I should try?

This is the rt2 grammar,

```
grammar rt2 ;

// parser rules
rt2Files : (rt2File)+ ;

rt2File : (regHdr (regRow | emptyRow)+) | (blockHdr (blockRow | emptyRow)+) | (memHdr (memRow | emptyRow)+) ;

regHdr : REG_NAME (',' regHdrField)+ NEWLINE ;
regHdrField : ( REG_HDR_FIELD | field );

memHdr : MEM_NAME (',' memHdrField)+ NEWLINE ;
memHdrField : ( MEM_HDR_FIELD | field );

blockHdr :  BLOCK_NAME (',' blockHdrField)+ NEWLINE ;
blockHdrField : (BLOCK_HDR_FIELD | field );

regRow : row ;
blockRow : row ;
memRow : row ;

row  : field (',' field)* (',' primtype)? (',' field)*  NEWLINE ;

emptyRow : (',')+ NEWLINE ;

field : TEXT    # text
      | STRING  # string
      |         # empty
      ;

primtype : REGISTER | MEMORY | BLOCK ;


// lexer rules

BLOCK_HDR_FIELD : ('Component Name'
          |'Instance Name'
          |'Type'
          |'Address' );

MEM_HDR_FIELD : ('Memory Name'
            |'Memory Width'
            |'Memory Range'
            |'Memory Access'
            |'Memory Description'
            |'Memory Constraints'
        |'Channel Used'
        |'Channel Count');

REG_HDR_FIELD : ('Width'
            |'Access'
            |'Reset Value'
            |'Field Name'
            |'Field Offset'
            |'Field Width'
            |'Field is Reserved'
            |'Field is Covered'
            |'Register Description'
            |'Field Description'
        |'Export');

BLOCK_NAME : 'Block Name' ;
REG_NAME : 'Register Name' ;
MEM_NAME : 'Memory Name' ;

REGISTER : 'register' ;
MEMORY   : 'memory' ;
BLOCK    : 'block' ;

NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n';
TEXT : ~[,\n\r"]+ ;
STRING : '"' ('""' | ~'"')* '"' ;
```

A bare bones python driver to trigger the error

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import io
from antlr4 import *

from rt2Lexer import *
from rt2Parser import rt2Parser
from rt2Listener import rt2Listener

class DefPhase(rt2Listener):

    def __init__(self, output):
        super().__init__(output)
        pass

    def enterRt2Files(self, ctx):
        self.globals = GlobalScope(None)
        self.currentScope = self.globals

    
if __name__ =='__main__':

    input_stream = FileStream('rt2.csv')
    lexer = rt2Lexer(input_stream)
    token_stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = rt2Parser(token_stream)
    tree = parser.rt2Files()
    walker = ParseTreeWalker()
```

Simple input file (rt2.py) to parse

```
,,,,,,,,
Register Name,Width, Access,Reset Value,Field Name,Field Offset,Field Width,Register Description,Field Description
,,,,,,,,
pl_output_ctrl,32,RW,0x0000_000C,TPG_EN,0,1,Pixel Link Test pattern control,1 : Enable the testpattern generator
,,,,,,,,
Block Name,Component Name,Type,Address,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
pl_control_block,pl_output_ctrl,register,0x000,,,,,
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same ANTLR runtime version as the version of the ANTLR tool that you used to generate your lexer and parser classes? Can you update your question and add a grammar and Python driver script that produces this error?

Comment: @BartKiers, Grammar,, strtipped down parser and some test tokens added to the initial question. I'm not certain the run times are the same, and it does seem to be the most likely cause. So far I haven't found a mechanism to have my target program report any antlr4 configuration information to chase it down. I've been attempting to just reinstall to clear that but I don't think I'm doing a good enough job of it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce that error. But the example input does not get accepted by your parser because of the leading comma's (but that produces a different error). The grammar does not allow the input to start with a `emptyRow`. If I fix that by removing the comma's, things parse fine:

```py
from rt2Lexer import *
from rt2Parser import rt2Parser


if __name__ == '__main__':
    source = """Register Name,Width, Access,Reset Value,Field Name,Field Offset,Field Width,Register Description,Field Description
,,,,,,,,
pl_output_ctrl,32,RW,0x0000_000C,TPG_EN,0,1,Pixel Link Test pattern control,1 : Enable the testpattern generator
,,,,,,,,
Block Name,Component Name,Type,Address,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
pl_control_block,pl_output_ctrl,register,0x000,,,,,
"""
    input_stream = InputStream(source)
    lexer = rt2Lexer(input_stream)
    token_stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = rt2Parser(token_stream)
    tree = parser.rt2Files()
    print(tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))
```

The following get printed:

```
(rt2Files 
  (rt2File 
    (regHdr Register Name , (regHdrField Width) , (regHdrField (field  Access)) , (regHdrField Reset Value) , (regHdrField Field Name) , (regHdrField Field Offset) , (regHdrField Field Width) , (regHdrField Register Description) , (regHdrField Field Description) \n) 
    (regRow (row field , field , field , field , field , field , field , field , field \n)) 
    (regRow (row (field pl_output_ctrl) , (field 32) , (field RW) , (field 0x0000_000C) , (field TPG_EN) , (field 0) , (field 1) , (field Pixel Link Test pattern control) , (field 1 : Enable the testpattern generator) \n)) 
    (regRow (row field , field , field , field , field , field , field , field , field \n))) 
  (rt2File 
    (blockHdr Block Name , (blockHdrField Component Name) , (blockHdrField Type) , (blockHdrField Address) , (blockHdrField field) , (blockHdrField field) , (blockHdrField field) , (blockHdrField field) , (blockHdrField field) \n) 
    (blockRow (row field , field , field , field , field , field , field , field , field \n)) 
    (blockRow (row (field pl_control_block) , (field pl_output_ctrl) , (primtype register) , (field 0x000) , field , field , field , field , field \n))))
```

(I only added a few line breaks in the output above)